# Does news "broadcast" on television or "telecast"?

Tags: word-choice

When it comes to news do we say news 'telecast' or news 'broadcast' on television? What's the correct term?

Like in an example do we say

*News is broadcasting* or *news is telecasting*

Comment: What are you trying to say? Please provide more details. In particular, do mean to have "news broadcast" as a noun, or "broadcast" as a verb. The same question applies to "telecast".

Comment: Generally you would use _broadcast_. The person doing it is a _broadcaster_. _Telecast_ is, I think, quite rare, and a _telecaster_ is a [guitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fender_Telecaster)!

Answer (score 1):

The two seem correct, technically. I think they sound a little strange for several reasons. I assume that *news* refers to information and not some kind of organization.

1. In the two examples, the verbs are likely being used as intransitives. It does not make sense if the news is the one doing the broad/telecasting.
2. I feel like you are likely to hear

   > The news **is being** broad/telecast.

   One could easily say

   > This station **broadcasts** the news nightly.

   for example.
3. Although *telecast* is correct in definition, from my own experience, it's usage seems uncommon. I provide some search results.
   [image]

   Notice the decline in the usage of the word *telecast* in recent years.
4. One of the reasons *broadcast* dominates in the figure above is because it does not just refer to television. It can also refer to radio and, in particular, the internet. So if you want to refer to television, then you should say

   > The news is broadcast on television nightly.

   for example.

   And again, you could say

   > The news is telecast nightly.

   for example, but because *telecast* is an uncommon word, I believe it would sound strange to many people.

Comment: Telecast as a verb wasn't recorded until 1940 (around the time televisions became more than scientific curiosities), so to be fair, you should limit your NGram to after that period. Before then, broadcast seems to be limited to agriculture and then radio broadcasts, which isn't really a good comparison.